# Is there a way to check if a .exe (or process) is running on a remote computer?

Tags: c++, windows

I wrote a program that I deployed on multiple machines. I'd like a way to monitor if they are running or not. Assuming this is not possible, is there a way that my program sends a message to my pc saying `Hey I'm running!` or something? Any ideas can help.

Comment: This is a really broad question about how to implement a socket based application.

Comment: I doubt this is going to generate any good answers because it's too broad. Why don't you search for C++ communication/network libraries and see if any of them match what you want to do?

Comment: You can send a message from the program itself, or you can write another program to query the operating system and send the message.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you comments. I am still new on english language. I am trying to connect to a computer and see if a specific process is running. I was wondering if it was possible to scan processes run on a remote machine

Comment: Have you tried searching for the answer online? [Here are 7 ways](https://www.devopsonwindows.com/7-ways-to-manage-windows-processes-remotely/). Why do you want to use C++?

Comment: You can do *everything* with C++. The difficult thing is to find, choose, understand an integrate the appropriate library for a particular task, at the appropriate level of abstraction. Your question is way too broad! It's like asking "how do I use French to write a fantasy novel".

Comment: Without the C++ tag, this question belongs on SuperUser, not here. And I see no reason for this to be tagged C++, besides "I wrote a program", and even then, that's overtly vague.

Comment: Well I am here to learn! Thanks for your input. I will rework my question. I understand what you mean. Thank you Christian and Wally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Windows XP there is a built-in command line utility named “tasklist“. By running the command “tasklist /s hostname” where “hostname” is the remote computer you want to query, it will return a list of processes on the remote machine and some basic details about each process (PID, session number, memory usage, etc.).